# Cloned form fields VALUES are not recognized to be emailed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a order form. Customer can place multiple orders for a products and associated accessories. One section of teh order having orderType and Qunatities are cloned based on customer selection of a no. of order fields. Issue is once form is submitted, content is grabbed and emailed. But Cloned values NOT are received. Non-cloned values are received.

C# code gets the form values except cloned ones.

```
//Code sample for fields
Page.FormFields.Add(new FormField() { FieldName = "orderType12", FieldLabel = "Order Type *", ErrorText = "Please select order type" });
Page.FormFields.Add(new FormField() { FieldName = "orderTypeOther12", FieldLabel = "Please specify", ErrorText = "Please specify" });
```

```
//SELECT CHANGE FUNCTION (on change get value and clone)
$('#case').change(function () {  // on change...
var numOfClones = $(this).val()-1;    // get value...
$('#firstCase').show();
$('#caseNumber.old').show();
$('#holder').html('');              // empty holder if there are some old clones
$('#caseNumber.old').duplicate(numOfClones).addClass('new').appendTo('#holder').show();

$('#caseNumber.new').each(function (idx) {
        idx = $(this).index() + 2;
        $('select', this).each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + idx).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
        });
        $('input', this).each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + idx).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
        });
        $('#caseNumbering', this).each(function () {
            $(this).text("Case Number " + idx++);
        });
    });
});
```

Below code is getting COntent for email

```
//get content for mailing
private static string GetMailContent(List<FormField> formFields)
{
    string path;
    var emailViewName = "OrderFormEmailChina.cshtml";
    path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Views/" + emailViewName);
    string readText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    string mailContent = readText;
    string fieldContent = "";
    foreach (FormField formField in formFields)
    {
        if (formField.FieldName == "")
        {
            mailContent += "";
        } Return mailContent;
    .......... FURTHER CODE
}
```

EMAIL FORMAT for OrderFormEmailChina.cshtml

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Hospital Name</th>
            <td>[hospitalName-req]</td>
            <th>Purchase Order</th>
            <td>[purchaseOrder-req]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <td>[accountNum-req]</td>
            <th>Patient ID</th>
            <td>[patientId]</td>
        </tr>
```

I am not getting cloned values in mailContent (debug mode) or in email.

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Its ASP.NET c# and jquery order from